formula salesforce that includes isblank and 0 conditions
I have two conditions to include inside a formula field of type percent:

If Trained__C is empty, result should be 0%,
If Trained__c is equal to 0, result should be 20%,
Else, result should be equal to a ratio (fieldA__c/fieldB__c)*20%, and result should not exceed 20%.

I tried multiple formula versions but the result is not as expected: When Trained__C is empty, result shows 20%, whereas result should be 0% as aforementioned.
Versions I tried with no success so far: Am I missing something? Thanks.
----- V1 -----
IF(
    ISBLANK(
        Target__c),
        0,
        IF(
            Target__c = 0,
            0.20,
            MIN(0.20,(fieldA__c/FieldB__c)*0.20)
    )
)

----- V2 -----
IF(
    ISNULL(
        Target__c),
        0,
        IF(
            Target__c = 0,
            0.20,
            MIN(0.20,(fieldA__c/FieldB__c)*0.20)
    )
)

----- V3 -----
IF(
    ISBLANK(
        Target__c),
        0,
        IF(
            Target__c = 0,
            0.20,
            IF(
                Target__c > 0,
                MIN(0.20,(fieldA__c/FieldB__c)*0.20),
                0
            )
        )
    )

----- V4 -----
IF(
    BLANKVALUE(Target__c,0) = 0,
    IF(
        ISBLANK(Target__c),
        0,
        0.20
    ),
    MIN(0.20,(fieldA__c/FieldB__c)*0.20)
)


Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Have you confirmed the "Treat blank fields as blank" setting in your formula field setup?

What do you have selected for the formula's null handling? Treat Blanks as Blanks, or Treat Blanks as Zeros?

Hi Derek, it was set to "Treat blank fields as zeroes". I switch to "Treat blank fields as blanks" and now it works as expected. Thank you!!
